# How to remove a LocationListener from LocationManager that is added twice in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

If I add `this` as a LocationListener twice as follows

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,3,this);
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,3,this);
```

, would it be enough to just remove `this` once as follows

```
manager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, removing `manager.removeUpdates(this);` is enough. As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)) says:

Removes any current registration for location updates of the current activity with the given LocationListener. Following this call, updates will no longer occur for this listener.

Comment: Am I allowed to call this method anywhere like `onPause`  or `onStop` ? Or should I call it only on `onLocationChanged` method??????``